# How can I progress in my career

Tags: career-development

firstly I am new to the forum so thank you for anyone who takes the time to read my question! I look forward to being an active member, and sorry for the length (Never thought I'd say that!)

Currently I work as an Operations Manager for a SME business that employs around 70 staff. I have worked in the role for just shy of two years, and am begging to feel as if I am getting stuck in a bit of a rut.

I honestly don't know how I have managed to get the job I have (was recommended in to the role) but somehow with no previous experience I have managed to be not only running but actively changing the people and organisational structure of a business that turns over 3m a year.

Before I go on i'll give a brief description of my past:

Failed at school highest GCSE was one C
Went to college, dropped out no grades.

Worked for a retail store in 4 years went from sales colleague, to team leader to assistant store manager then seconded store manager before getting my current role as an Operations Manager.

Firstly I'm pretty good at my job, honestly don't know how with no real business experience and being an academic failure.

Over the last two years I have worked with an SME business and some of the key things I have done are:

- Transitioned colleagues from umbrella company to employees (my decision)
- Created job profiles for all colleagues within the business
- Structured, recruited and managed accounts/finance manager
- structured recruited and managed HR Manager (CIPD Level 5)
- Implemented monthly colleague reviews across the business
- Created pay bands and career progression for all roles below manager
- Made redundancies where needed to improve business efficiency
- Increased Profit YOY by 40%
- re negotiated prices with customers and suppliers

Plus a lot more.

Here's my problem, i'm paid OK for what I do.. I'm 25 no education and earn 30K plus I get a nice company car, and fuel so my package works out around 40k if not a little more.

But I can't stand my boss and it's time to move on, my boss spends maybe only 1 day in the business a month but I can't work with him anymore he's crazy.

I mean he employed an uneducated, assistant manager of a retail store to run his business, i'm sure you can tell he's not quiet right lol!

But where do I go from here, I can talk all day about what I have done from people and organisational change within my current business but no one will look at me! I'm assuming because of my education?

I'm single, no real family support and bills, I can't just give up work and go in to education again. My current job has me working 15 hour days mon-fri and usually a Saturday as well so working around this will also be hard.

I would like to know, if you guys we're in my position what would you do, any why.

I will add a little disclaimer in here as a lot of people reading this would probably just say stay in your job.. I can't do that because I really can't stress how much of a psychopath my boss really is, so please take that in to consideration :)

Again, apologies for the length, and I'm sure there are a lot of spelling mistakes in here so please don't be to critical :')

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to The Workplace! We work a little differently from your usual forum. I encourage you to take a look at our [tour] and our [help]. Right now your question is doesn't include a clear goal, and we don't give generic career advice here. Take a look at our [off-topic reasons](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696) for more explanation on what sorts of questions we are looking for here. I hope you can find some useful information on our site, and welcome again!

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this answer is given with information from the US.

You need to get your resume ready and start applying for jobs. You have some valuable experience, and if you sit down with someone who can help you sell it right, then you ought to be able to be a candidate for managing stores at a minimum.

From your question, it seems like you doubt you can get a job that pays you similarly due to your education. First, let me start by pointing out that $30-40k ought to be reachable. If you work 40 hours a week 50 weeks an hour, then $40k translates to about $20 / hour. Assuming you are able bodied, you ought to be able to find that much from a construction job. Additionally, glassdoor.com claims that McDonald's managers [average $50k](https://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/mcdonalds-store-manager-salary-SRCH_KO0,23.htm) annually. It seems like you ought to be able to create a resume that would convince them or a similar company to let you manage a store. Either of those kinds of jobs would give you much more free time than working 15 hours a day; you would have enough time to go back to school if you wanted to. In fact, if you work on average 60 hours a week then $40k means you only make $13.33 an hour.

TL;DR what you are paid isn't worth being overworked and you ought to be able to find that level of pay without a college degree.

Comment: Not sure if it affects your answer, but I think the op is UK based, 40k GBP converts to ~56k USD. UK average salary is ~ 26.5 GBP for context.

Comment: Thanks for calling that out; I wasn't sure if the British spellings were typos or intentional since OP called out spelling mistakes. My guess would be that this is still a very attainable salary in the UK; also, I thought the UK actually had labor laws protecting workers?

Comment: Said otherwise : US's salaries seem very high because you have to pay everything. in the UK, there is a comprehensive health care system. In France, nearly so, but you add other perks, like joblessness insurance, or pensions. Which makes income between countries impossible to compare, before even normalizing for life costs.